VSCode dev-containers unable to import npm packages
I've spent lots of time debugging why I can't resolve imports in VSCode Dev-Container IDE – MY REPO.
When I start my frontend dev-container, the imports from /node_modules return error "Cannot find module".

I checked the docker container and the packages are in-fact installed.
If I install the packages locally, the issue is resolved, but I was under the impression that the entire point of dev-containers was to isolate this.
My python dev-container has no trouble in finding the docker interpreter and importing pip packages.
Below is the Dockerfile, docker-compose, and .devcontainer.
frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace:cached # Mount the root folder that contains .git
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development

# Use the official Node.js 18 image, Alpine version.
FROM node:20-alpine

# Install Git and OpenSSH
RUN apk add --no-cache git openssh

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /frontend

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json, and install dependencies.
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy the rest of the files
COPY . .

# Expose the port the app runs on.
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the development server using the `dev` script from your package.json.
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

{ 
  "name": "Frontend Development",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../../docker-compose.yml"],
    "service": "frontend",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace/frontend",
    "shutdownAction": "none",
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true

      },
      "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
      ]
    }
  },
  "mounts": [
    "type=bind,source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace",
    "type=bind,source=/Users/${localEnv:USER}/.ssh,target=/root/.ssh,readonly"
  ]
}

I've tried creating a volume for node_modules so that there is not conflict with local files too, but that hasn't helped.
Nothing has worked.

Ok I finally solved the issue.
All I had to do was align the dev-container workspaceFolder with that of the running docker container. Changing /workspace/frontend to /frontend.
This is very obvious in hindsight, I should've understood this.
"workspaceFolder": "/frontend",

and changing the docker-compose
frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/frontend:cached
      - /frontend/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development

